# Why does the Y label come up as the number 1 even though i specify the text in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph of my data and for some reason when I try and set the Y label, it doesn't work and puts the label as "1" even though using the same code works for the x label. Any help with this would be appreciated. It still does not work if I remove the xlab code and the ylab is all that's left. My Code and a picture of the graph is below

```
ggplot(twohour, aes(x = Treatmentinorder, y = Total, fill = Treatment)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,500),
                     breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 100),1) +
  
  geom_boxplot(notch=F,  
               outlier.shape= NA, 
               width=0.7,
               lwd=0.5,
               fatten=1,
               color="black",
               position=position_dodge(0.7)) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom= "point", size=2, position=position_dodge(1), color="black") +
  labs (x= "Heatwave exposure group", y= "20 day reproductive output") +
  geom_jitter(shape=1, size=1.5, position=position_jitter(0.25))+
  
  
theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        axis.text.x=element_text(color="black", size=12),
        axis.text.y=element_text(color="black", size=12),
        axis.title.x=element_text(face = "bold", size=12),
        axis.title.y=element_text(face = "bold", size=12))`
```

edited to remove the graph of my work, thanks for the help.

Comment: It's because `1` is supplied as an unnamed argument to the y scale in `breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 100),1)`. To fix it, replace it with `breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 100))` instead. The first argument of a scale is the name, so the unnamed argument becomes the name and therefore the title of the y axis. There is a hierarchy to where axis labels are specified and they are from bottom to top: 1. inferred from aesthetics, 2. specified in `labs()`/`xlab()`/`ylab()`, 3. given as the name of a scale and 4. given as title in `guide_axis()`. Because of this hierarchy, `labs()` doesn't overrule the scale.

Comment: Thank you. Removed the 1 and it is sorted.